# Verifying the data from two arraylist and delete it

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a master arraylist call toBeDeleted which stored timestamp and email. The following are the sample data inside the toBeDeleted arraylist

```
[1507075234, bunny@outlook.com]
```

I have one arraylist call logData1 which stored status,email,timestamps and ID. The following are the sample data inside the logData1 arraylist.

```
[16, bunny@outlook, 1507075234, 0OX9VQB-01-00P-02]
```

I hope to delete the data inside the logData1 arraylist by verifying the timestamp first with timestamps stated in toBeDeleted1 arraylist, if the timestamp matched, I will check the email for both arraylist. If both of them are matched, I would like to delete away all the data (status,email,timestamp,ID). But I cant make it work 

this is my sample output from my source code

```
[16, bunny@outlook.com, 1507075234, 0OX9VQB-01-00P-02]
The data inside toBeDeleted1 is :[1507075234, bunny@outlook.com]
The time1 is :1507075234
The email1 is :bunny@outlook.com
The time is :1507075234
The emails is :bunny@outlook.com
The data is :bunny@outlook.com
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -3
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at EmailReporting.main(EmailReporting.java:83)
```

This is my sample program

```
   System.out.println(logData1);
   System.out.println("The data inside toBeDeleted1 is :"+toBeDeleted1);
         for(int v = 0;v<toBeDeleted1.size();v++)  //look through the logdata1 for removing the record base on timestamp 
         {
           String time1 = toBeDeleted1.get(v);
           String email1 = toBeDeleted1.get(v+1);
           System.out.println("The time1 is :"+time1);
           System.out.println("The email1 is :"+email1);
           for(int f = logData1.size();f>logData1.size()-1;f--)
           {
            //   System.out.println(logData1.size());
            //   System.out.println("The data in logdata1 is "+logData1.get(f-2));
               if(time1.equals(logData1.get(f-2)))
               {
                   System.out.println("The time is :"+logData1.get(f-2));
                 System.out.println("The emails is :"+logData1.get(f-3));
                   if(email1.equals(logData1.get(f-3)))
                   {
                     System.out.println("The data is :"+logData1.get(f-3));
                       logData1.remove(f-1);
                       logData1.remove(f-2);
                       logData1.remove(f-3);
                       logData1.remove(f-4);
                       f-=4;   
                   }

               }
           }
         }
```

The error occurred after this line of code executed

```
System.out.println("The data is :"+logData1.get(f-3));
```

Comment: Which line is the failure on? Please [edit] your code to indicate it.

Comment: Note: don't delete one element at a time from a list. Use `logData.subList(f-4, f).clear()`.

Comment: What is the point in the loop in `f`? It will only execute once.

Comment: subList(f-4,f) will delete the element from index 0 to index 4  ? because I need to delete all related data if the final matching is fulfilled

Comment: the f is for the "for loop" to loop out the element from the arraylist

Comment: The `f` loops between `size` and `size-1`. This will only execute once.

Comment: any idea for make it loop through whole arraylist in descending order because I need to delete data,so better loop it through descending order

Comment: Umm... `f>0` would be a good start, but really should be `f>4` since you have `f-4` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find elements in the list in order using `Collections.indexOfSubList`:

```
List<String> toFind = Arrays.asList(time1, email1);
int emailIndex = Collections.indexOfSubList(logData1, toFind);
```

A similar `lastIndexOfSubList` method also exists. That might be more appropriate for your use case.

You can then use this to remove the elements from `toFind`:

```
int emailIndex = Collections.lastIndexOfSubList(logData1, toFind);
if (emailIndex >= 1) {
  logData1.subList(emailIndex-1, emailIndex+3).clear();
}
```

Just do this in a loop to keep going until all occurrences have been removed.

Note that just doing this in a loop naively will keep on searching over the tail of the list repeatedly. Instead, you can use `subList` to "chop" the end of the list, to avoid re-searching it:

```
List<String> view = logData1;
int emailIndex;
while ((emailIndex = Collections.lastIndexOfSubList(view, toFind)) >= 1) {
  logData1.subList(emailIndex-1, emailIndex+3).clear();
  view = logData1.subList(0, emailIndex-1);
}
```

---

Additionally, note that deleting from the middle of an `ArrayList` is inefficient, because the elements after the ones you delete have to be shifted down. This is why using `subList(...).clear()` is *better*, because it does all of those shifts at once. But if you are removing lots of 4-element batches, you can do better.

Instead of the `subList(...).clear()`, you can set the bits of elements to be deleted into a `BitSet`:

```
List<String> view = logData1;
BitSet bits = new BitSet(logData1.size());
int emailIndex;
while ((emailIndex = Collections.lastIndexOfSubList(view, toFind)) >= 1) {
  bits.set(emailIndex-1, emailIndex+3);
  view = logData1.subList(0, emailIndex-1);
}
```

And then shift all the elements down at once, discarding the elements you want to delete:

```
int dst = 0;
for (int src = 0; src < logData1.size(); ++src) {
  if (!bits.get(src)) {
    logData1.set(dst++, logData1.get(src));
  }
}
```

And now truncate the list:

```
logData1.subList(dst, logData1.size());
```

Comment: I will admit there is a lot to digest here if you've not seen it before. I wrote it in such a way that it builds up: try working through it with a debugger.

Comment: I managed to solve it by changing my own logic for the for loop, I admitted that your method will be more clean for doing it , thanks for sharing and hope others people saw a more clean way for doing it